# Home Page components not showing for some assigned users

Tags: home-page-component

Some of the standard components are showing up for users whose profile is assigned to the Home Page Layout. There are others with the same profile who see the components.

The components include Tasks, Items To Approve, Dashboard Snapshot, and Paused Flow Interviews.

I've done a comparison of the users on Perm Comparator and there are no Setup Entity permissions between the two.

Any ideas on this ?

Thank you.

Comment: lightning communities?

Comment: are the permissions sets allowed under the community management> members tab

Comment: I don't understand what communities has to do with this ... ? We don't even use it. I can't even get Tasks or Items To Approve to appear. Full Salesforce license. They appear for others with the same Perm Sets, Profile, and Role.

Comment: You mentioned components in your home page, home page of what? you mentioned home page layout,  it can be of a lightning app, a lightning community, salesforce home page tab of an app..... just asking to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I'm not using Lightning. I am talking about the standard 'Home' tab. If you go into setup and type 'Home' in quick searchit will come up with Home Page Layout ; and "Home Page Component" choices. You can then put together different "Home Page Layouts" and assign them to profiles using different Home Page Components (Tasks, Items To Approve, Dashboard Snapshot, Paused Flow Interviews)

Answer (score 0):

If the "Paused Flow Interviews" checkbox is checked, try unchecking it. This change has resolved the issue for my users.